# Pixel axis conversion in PIL

Tags: numpy, matplotlib, python-imaging-library

I'm trying to build a program to automatically extract data from an image of a plot.  I nearly have it but am hung up on defining the desired axis from pixel coordinates.  For example if this image is being used:

[image]

I can find the data points but the points are in reference to the image size and look like this:
[image]

What is the best way to make this conversion?

Comment: Actually, no code is necessary. This is just a small math problem converting coordinates from one system to another.

Comment: The code is rather long to post.  @MichielOvertoom 's answer was exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be done with some math. You have to convert the coordinates from pixels to plot values, like so:

- squash the domain to 0...1
- mirror (only for the y-axis, since the pixel y-coordinates run from top to bottom and the plot coordinates from bottom to top)
- expand the domain to the range on the plot

For example, take one of your data points, which has the pixel coordinate (80, 150), from the graph I can see that its coordinate on the plot is (24, 8.75).

Let's do the y-coordinate first, is has to map from 150 to 8.75:

- divide by the y-range of the image (200): 150/200 = 0.75
- mirror: 1 - 0.75 = 0.25
- expand: 0.25 * 35 (the y-range of the plot) = 8.75

Then the x-coordinate, no mirroring necessary:

- 80/300 = 0.2666
- 0.2666 * 90 = 24

I'm not sure if the axes are part of your image, if they are, you might also have to apply some offsets to account for them.